# Spring Interceptors configured in root ApplicationContext cannot be reached from child WebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor, applicationcontext

Ok I understand the fact that any web application context configured through DispatcherServlet inherits all the beans already defined in the root WebApplicationContext. Nevertheless i have configured some interceptors in my root ApplicationContext

```
     <bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
                <property name="order" value="2"/>
                <property name="interceptors">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="statisticsInterceptor"/>
                        <ref bean="sessionDiagnosticsInterceptor"/>
...
```

Then in my web.xml I have something like this:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
           <init-param>
               <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                 <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
                 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher-api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/appOtherContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher-api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/example/apiOther/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

So the problem I have is that every time I go to any URL that contains "**/example/apiOther/**", the Interceptors will not be reached/run. My question is: **WHY?** What is the scope of the handlerMapping? I thought that because it is in the root applicationContext it should apply to all child contexts. I've been doing some research and I think that HandlerMappings are limited to its context even if it is the root Context. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

As you configure your interceptors through `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, they will be used only for controllers in same ApplicationContext. You can (even it is not very nice) declare the interceptors in root application context, provided the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` that referes to them is declared in servlet application context where you declare your controllers, either directly or through annotations.